# std::promise::set_value on FIFO thread pinned to a core doesn't wake std::future

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, real-time, scheduler

I am trying to create a system which has a deterministic realtime response.

I create a number of [`cpusets`](http://code.google.com/p/cpuset/), move all non-critical tasks and unpinned kernel threads to one set, and then pin each of my realtime threads to its own cpuset, each of which consists of a single cpu.

```
$ non-critical tasks and unpinned kernel threads
cset proc --move --fromset=root --toset=system
cset proc --kthread --fromset=root --toset=system

$ realtime threads
cset proc --move --toset=shield/RealtimeTest1/thread1 --pid=17651
cset proc --move --toset=shield/RealtimeTest1/thread2 --pid=17654
```

My scenario is this:

- Thread 1: `SCHED_OTHER`, pinned to `set1`, waiting on `std::future<void>`
- Thread 2: `SCHED_FIFO`, pinned to `set2`, calls `std::promise<void>::set_value()`

**Thread 1 blocks forever.** 
However, **if I change Thread 2 so be `SCHED_OTHER`**, Thread 1 is able to continue.

I have run an `strace -f` to get more insight; it seems Thread 1 is waiting on a `futex` (I assume the internals of `std::future`) but is never woken up.

I'm absolutely stymied - is there any way to have a thread pin itself to a core and set its scheduler to FIFO , and then use a `std::promise` to wake up another thread which is waiting for it to complete this so-called realtime setup?

The code for thread1 creating thread2 is as follows:

```
// Thread1:
std::promise<void> p;
std::future <void> f = p.get_future();

_thread = std::move(std::thread(std::bind(&Dispatcher::Run, this, std::ref(p))));

LOG_INFO << "waiting for thread2 to start" << std::endl;

if (f.valid())
    f.wait();
```

and the *Run* function for thread2 is as follows:

```
// Thread2:
LOG_INFO << "started: threadId=" << Thread::GetId() << std::endl;

Realtime::Service* rs = Service::Registry::Lookup<Realtime::Service>();
if (rs)
    rs->ConfigureThread(this->Name()); // this does the pinning and FIFO etc

LOG_INFO << "thread2 has started" << std::endl;
p.set_value(); // indicate fact that the thread has started
```

The strace output follows:

- Thread 1 is `[pid 17651]`
- Thread 2 is `[pid 17654]`

In the interests of brevity I have removed some of the output.

```
//////// Thread 1 creates thread 2 and waits on a future ////////

[pid 17654] gettid()                    = 17654
[pid 17651] write(2, "09:29:52 INFO waiting for thread"..., 4309:29:52 INFO waiting for thread2 to start
 <unfinished ...>
[pid 17654] gettid( <unfinished ...>
[pid 17651] <... write resumed> )       = 43
[pid 17654] <... gettid resumed> )      = 17654
[pid 17651] futex(0xd52294, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 17654] gettid()                    = 17654
[pid 17654] write(2, "09:29:52 INFO thread2 started: t"..., 6109:29:52 INFO thread2  started: threadId=17654
) = 61

//////// <snip> thread2 performs pinning, FIFO, etc </snip> ////////

[pid 17654] write(2, "09:29:52 INFO thread2 has starte"..., 3409:29:52 INFO thread2 has started
) = 34
[pid 17654] futex(0xd52294, FUTEX_CMP_REQUEUE_PRIVATE, 1, 2147483647, 0xd52268, 2) = 1
[pid 17651] <... futex resumed> )       = 0
[pid 17654] futex(0xd522c4, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647 <unfinished ...>
[pid 17651] futex(0xd52268, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 17654] <... futex resumed> )       = 0
[pid 17651] <... futex resumed> )       = 0

//////// blocks here forever ////////
```

You can see that pid 17651 (thread1) reports `futex resumed`, but is it maybe running on the wrong cpu and getting blocked behind thread2 which is running as `FIFO`?

**Update: It seems this is an issue with threads *not running on the cpus they have been pinned to*.**

`top -p 17649 -H` with `f,j` to bring up the `last used cpu` shows that **thread 1 is indeed running on thread 2's cpu**.

```
top - 10:00:59 up 18:17,  3 users,  load average: 7.16, 7.61, 4.18
Tasks:   3 total,   2 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  7.1%us,  0.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 89.5%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  3.3%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   8180892k total,   722800k used,  7458092k free,    43364k buffers
Swap:  8393952k total,        0k used,  8393952k free,   193324k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  P COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                                             
17654 root      -2   0 54080  35m 7064 R  100  0.4   5:00.77 3 RealtimeTest                                                                                                                                                                                         
17649 root      20   0 54080  35m 7064 S    0  0.4   0:00.05 2 RealtimeTest                                                                                                                                                                                         
17651 root      20   0 54080  35m 7064 R    0  0.4   0:00.00 3 RealtimeTest
```

However, if I look at the `cpuset` filesystem, I can see that my tasks are *supposedly* pinned to the cpus I requested:

```
/cpusets/shield/RealtimeTest1 $ for i in `find -name tasks`; do echo $i; cat $i; echo "------------"; done

./thread1/tasks
17651 
------------
./main/tasks
17649 
------------
./thread2/tasks
17654
------------
```

Displaying the cpuset config:

```
$ cset set --list -r
cset: 
         Name       CPUs-X    MEMs-X Tasks Subs Path
 ------------ ---------- - ------- - ----- ---- ----------
         root       0-23 y     0-1 y   279    2 /
       system 0,2,4,6,8,10 n       0 n   202    0 /system
       shield 1,3,5,7,9,11 n       1 n     0    2 /shield
RealtimeTest1    1,3,5,7 n       1 n     0    4 /shield/RealtimeTest1
      thread1          3 n       1 n     1    0 /shield/RealtimeTest1/thread1
      thread2          5 n       1 n     1    0 /shield/RealtimeTest1/thread2
         main          1 n       1 n     1    0 /shield/RealtimeTest1/main
```

From this I would say that thread2 is *supposed* to be on cpu 5, but top says it's running on cpu 3.

Interestingly, `sched_getaffinity` reports what `cpuset` does - that thread1 is on cpu 3 and thread2 is on cpu 5.

However, looking at `/proc/17649/task` to find the `last_cpu` each of its tasks ran on:

```
/proc/17649/task $  for i in `ls -1`; do cat $i/stat | awk '{print $1 " is on " $(NF - 5)}'; done
17649 is on 2
17651 is on 3
17654 is on 3
```

**`sched_getaffinity` reports one thing, but reality is another**

Interestingly, `main` thread [`pid 17649`] is supposed to be on cpu 1 (according to the `cset` output), but in fact it is running on cpu 2 (which is on another socket)

So I would say that `cpuset` is not working?

My machine configuration is:

```
$ cat /etc/SuSE-release
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
VERSION = 11
PATCHLEVEL = 1
$ uname -a
Linux foobar 2.6.32.12-0.7-default #1 SMP 2010-05-20 11:14:20 +0200 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I'm not going to vote off-topic, but I'm really not sure this is the place to be asking such a specific question, as it deals with kernel configuration more than user-code. Maybe try on [SuperUser.SE](http://superuser.com/)?

Comment: @ildjarn - thanks - I will do so

Comment: I have put a question on serverfault: http://serverfault.com/questions/402575/cpusets-not-working-threads-arent-running-in-the-cpuset-i-specified

Comment: The code here looks similar in many ways to the code posted on another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843304/race-condition-in-pthread-once   Is this question 'answered' by the other one, or is this question about a different problem in the same/similar code?

Comment: @MichaelBurr - I think you may be right, it could very well be - I will use `std::move` on the promise and let you know the outcome

Comment: @MichaelBurr - sadly no, this is a different problem. I think it is a Suse11 SP1 error, because I ran this under SP2 and the pinning worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reran the tests on a **SLES 11 / SP 2** box, and the pinning works.

As such, I'm going to mark this as an answer, which is: This is an issue related to **SP 1**