# What is the recommend way to add custom flag (-fsanitize=thread) when building gcc/libstdc++ from source?

Tags: c++, gcc, libstdc++

I am using thread sanitizer to debug my code, and [the comment in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37587096/thread-sanitizer-reports-data-race-when-using-stdpackaged-task-stdexception) mentioned to avoid false positive brought by newer C++ features such as `std::thread` and `std::future`, I should compile the libstdc++ with -fsanitize=thread flag.

I have downloaded the source code of gcc 10 and have completed the default compilation. But what is the recommend way to add -fsanitize=thread to the libstdc++?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the developers and maintainers of gcc/libstdc++ use their own tools for sanity checking, and testing their library code. As such, I doubt that anything like that would add value, and would have a rather abysmal return on value.

Comment: The purpose is not to check the code of libstdc++, but to add necessary instruments for my code that links with the standard library to work properly. I think I saw a post from GCC developers saying this is the only way to avoid those false positives. I will post the link here also when I find it.

Comment: If you want to add the necessary instrumentation for your code, then you need to compile ***your*** code with instrumentation, and not gcc.

Comment: I already add instrument to my code. But the post I mentioned said that is not enough. The standard library should also be instrumented.